# Fetch documents in firestore according to timestamp

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I would like to fetch documents from Firestore which are 1 week old according to current sever timestamp, how can I achieve this?
Please tell me how to do it using Python SDK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore does not include automatic ordering. Therefore, you would need to store a timestamp with each document.

The Firestore documentation states:

> A Timestamp represents a point in time independent of any time zone or calendar, represented as seconds and fractions of seconds at nanosecond resolution in UTC Epoch time.

Using the Firebase Python SDK, you could query based on timestamp as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from firebase_admin import firestore


one_week_ago = datetime.now(timezone.utc) + timedelta(days=-7)

fs_client = firestore.client()
docs = fs_client.collection(collection_name).where('timestamp_field', "<=", one_week_ago).stream()

for doc in docs:
    print(u'{} => {}'.format(doc.id, doc.to_dict()))
```

Comment: Will this work if I've stored the documents with timestamp in the following manner: _{ timestamp: firestore.SERVER_TIMESTAMP }_ ?

Comment: `fs_client.collection(collection_name).where('timestamp_field', "<=",one_week_ago).get()` using this returns a generator object with all the queried documents. So, using `collection_ref.stream()` gave me an `AttributeError`. I resolved it by converting it to a dictionary.

Comment: @PranayAnkit The code has been updated. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I see you've used `stream()` here. What is the difference between `get()` and `stream()`?

Comment: `get()` is the deprecated version of `stream()` (they do the same thing).